# What might be a simpler way to code this?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, do-while

I'm writing a program that allows students to calculate the average number of students in each of their classes. At the moment, my code looks like this:

(double classes is the number of classes the student is taking, and the number of students in each class is assigned to class1, class2, etc.)

```
if (classes == 1) {
    System.out.printf("How many students are there in your 1 st class?%n");
    class1 = TextIO.getlnDouble();
    classes = classes + 1;
    System.out.printf("Do you have another class?");
    boolean response = TextIO.getlnBoolean();
  } else if (classes == 2);
```

et cetera, for all 9 possible classes. (My school only allows the credit equivalent of 6.5 classes to be taken in a single semester, but some of that may be made up of two-credit or non-credit classes.)

I could just make a loop out of this, but how would I assign the given number to the correct double? i.e. how could I swap out class1 for class2, class3, etc.?

Comment: What is `TextIO`? Is it from a library, if so, from which?

Comment: When you think you need numbered variables, you actually should think about using an array

Comment: Array, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
System.out.printf("How many classes are you taking?%n");
int classes = TextIO.getlnInt();
for(int class=1; class <= classes; class++) {
    System.out.printf("How many students are there in your %d class?%n", class);
    students += TextIO.getlnDouble();
}
double average = students / classes;
System.out.printf("There are on average %.2f students per class%n", average);
```

This code should do just what you asked for!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, loops will work. Arrays are a better way to store multiple variables of the same type

Are you ever going to have half a student? Use integers, not doubles

```
int[] students = new int[classes];
for (int c = 0; c < classes; c++) {
    System.out.printf("How many students are there in class #%d?%n", c);
    students[c] = TextIO.getlnInt();
}
```